# Discord.js Akairo Bot this.client.setInterval is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I am going through the [Akairo documents tutorial](https://discord-akairo.github.io/#/docs/main/master/basics/setup) to spin up a bot using the framework. I am using "dotenv" to load my token for the client.

```
require('dotenv').config();
const { AkairoClient, CommandHandler } = require('discord-akairo');

class MyClient extends AkairoClient {
  constructor() {
    super({
        ownerID: '123992700587343872', // not a real id
    }, {
        disableMentions: 'everyone',
        intents: ['GUILD_MESSAGES']
    });
    this.commandHandler = new CommandHandler(this, {
      directory: './commands/',
      prefix: '<3',
    });
    this.commandHandler.loadAll();
  }
}

const client = new MyClient();
client.login(process.env.TOKEN);
```

Every time I try and run the bot using the `node bot.js` command I get the following error [image: this.client.setInterval is not a function]

I have tried looking to make sure my dependencies are up to requirements and even tried a completely clean npm install of everything but I'm not sure what is wrong. I am currently using node 16.8.0 through nvm as well.

My code is posted [here](https://github.com/paulmedeiros92/AnimeBot) but is essentially just the above mentioned tutorial with the "dotenv" package added.

As mentioned below the problem stems from discord.js v13 no longer allowing Extendable structures. Is there a way I can modify this tutorial code to run with discord.js v13 instead of just deprecating down to v12?

Comment: [This](https://discordjs.guide/additional-info/changes-in-v13.html#structures-extend) should be your issue. So I guess you'll need to use discord.js v12 alongside that framework.

Comment: Downgraded to discord.js 12.1.0 and it works, thank you!

Comment: Discord-Akairo appears to be currently in the process of upgrading to discord.js v13, as you can see on their [Github](https://github.com/discord-akairo/discord-akairo). To use that framework with discord.js v13, you'll just need to wait for them to release their next update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Discord-Akairo appears to be currently in the process of upgrading to discord.js v13, as you can see on their [Github](https://github.com/discord-akairo/discord-akairo). To use that framework with discord.js v13.x, you'll just need to wait for them to release their next update.

Unless you are confident and knowledgeable enough to fork their repository, and edit the framework to work with v13 yourself. That would have the added advantage of being able to further customize the framework to your needs.

The reason you're getting the `"client.setInterval is not a function"` error is because Discord.js removed that method in v13. On top of that issue, extendable structures were removed, and there are hundreds of other breaking changes that would make it impossible to use the current version of Discord-Akairo with djs v13.

For now, unless you choose to fork Akairo, you'll need to downgrade to discord.js v12.x, as you've already done. It should work for now, but you will of course be missing out on many of the new Discord features such as threads, buttons, select menus, and slash commands.

You may also want to consider using a different framework that already has v13 support for now, perhaps some sort of similar framework so you can easily transfer back to Akairo later if you so choose.